# Class directive not working when using ng-class with condition

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried to load the directive as below but it is not working.

```
<div ng-class="{'nav-dropdown' : dt.url == null }"> </div>
```

It works fine if I just assigned it to a class like this:

```
<div class="nav-dropdown"> </div>
```

**EDIT:**

When using this method:

```
<div ng-class="{'nav-dropdown' : dt.url == null }"> </div>
```

The class is added inside html as

```
<div class="nav-dropdown"> </div>
```

The main problem is : the directive doesn't show up as

```
 <div class="nav-dropdown"><div>This is directive template</div></div>
```

**What I want to do is load the directive with a condition**: dt.url is null. Anyone can help?

Comment: dt is data. I load it from JSON data. I check if the url is null, then apply the class "nav-dropdown" for calling the directive to be displayed. @BidhanA, do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe the url isn't null and so the condition returns false. Have you checked it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ternary expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

```
<ng-class="condition ? 'true' : 'false'"></div>
```

So, instead use this:

```
<div ng-class="{'nav-dropdown' : dt.url == null }"> </div>
```

**You could use this:** (This works for me)

```
<div ng-class="dt.url == null ? 'nav-dropdown' : ''"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest evaluating it as either true or false as it seems that `ng-class` only evaluates to a boolean, so you should just use:

```
<div ng-class="{'nav-dropdown' : !dt.url }"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit after OP edit**

The directive `ng-class` is specifically for dynamically setting a CSS class, not a directive. The order in which the directives are evaluated is most likely complicating things (ex: the nav-dropdown directive would need to be compiled after the ng-class directive was evaluated).

To dynamically set a directive, maybe reconsider passing the data to the directive via the scope, and have the directive behave differently if 'url' is null.

Here is an updated fiddle demonstrating this:

http://jsfiddle.net/spanndemic/7Ltm9bfq/

html:

```
<div ng-app="docsSimpleDirective">
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
        <div nav-dropdown dropdown-data="dt1"></div>
        <div nav-dropdown dropdown-data="dt2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.dt1 = {
        url: null
    };
    $scope.dt2 = {
        url: 'http://www.google.com'
    };
}]).directive('navDropdown', function() {

    var _link = function($scope, element, attrs) {
        var el;
        if ($scope.dropdownData.url === null) {
            el = '<div>URL not set</div>';
        } else {
            el = '<div>URL is: ' + $scope.dropdownData.url + '</div>';
        }

        element.replaceWith(el);
    };

    return {
        replace: true,
        link: _link,
        scope: {
            dropdownData: '='
        }
    };
});
```